# retrieve part of the info in a cell in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I vaguely remember that it is possible to parse the data in a cell and keep only part of the data after setting up certain conditions. But I can't remember what exact commands to use. Any help/suggestion?

For example, A1 contains the following info

```
0/1:47,45:92:99:1319,0,1320
```

Is there a way to pick up, say, `0/1` or `1319,0,1320` and remove the rest unchosen data?
I know I can do `text-to-column` and set the `delimiter`, followed by manually removing the "un-needed" data, but my EXCEL spreadsheet contains 100 columns X 500000 rows with each cell looking similar to the data above, so I am afraid EXCEL may crash before finishing the work. (have been trying with `LEFT`, `LEN`, `RIGHT`, `MID`, but none seems to work the way I had hoped)
Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: not sure why the minus point, because I thought I've already given the input/output example in the original question ? input is "0/1:47,45:92:99:1319,0,1320" and output is either only "0/1" or only "1319,0,1320".

Comment: all cells look "similar" (as I said in the OP) - i.e. one cell looks `0/1:47,45:92:99:1319,0,1320`, another looks `0/0:22,0:22:60:0,5,5`, yet another looks `1/1:100:5:10,1000,0`. so one new spreadsheet should look like `A1:0/1, A2:0/0, A3:1/1` while another spreadsheet looks like `A1:99,A2:60,A3:5` (second to the last data, separated by :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is combination of find and mid, but you'll have to work out exactly how you want to split your string:

```
A1 = 0/1:47,45:92:99:1319,0,1320  //your number
B1 = Find(“:“,A1)               //location of first ":" symbol
C1 = LEN(A1) - B1                 //character count to copy ( possibly requires +1 or -1 after B1.
=Left(A1,B1)                      //left of your symbol
=Mid(A1,B1+1,C1)                  //right size from your symbol (you can also replace C1 with better defined number to extract only 1 portion
//You can also nest the statements to save space, but usually at cost of processing quantity increase
```

This is the concept, you will probably need to do it in multiple cells to split a string as long as yours. For multiple splits you probably want to replicate this command to target the result of previous right/mid command.
That way, you will get cell result sequence like:
0/1:47,45:92:99:1319,0,1320; 47,45:92:99:1319,0,1320; 92:99:1319,0,1320; 99:1319,0,1320......
From each of those you can retrieve left side of the string up to ":" to get each portion of a string.

If you are working with a large table you probably want to look into VB scripting. To my knowledge there is no single excel command that can take 1 cell and split it into multiple ones.

Comment: Thanks. been toying with them, but hoping to find a "one-liner" type of formula. Splitting the data will generate a BIGGER file that is for me even harder to find the info in the post-split file.

Comment: I usually keep my calculations on far right. But really, if size is a problem for you, DO look into Excel VB.

Answer (score 0):

Given you statement of having 100x columns I imagine in some instances you are needing to isolate characters in the middle of your string, thus `Left` and `Right` may not always work.  However, where possible use them where you can.
Assuming your string is in cell F2: `0/1:47,45:92:99:1319,0,1320`

```
=LEFT(F2,3)
```

This returns `0/1` which are the first 3 characters in the string counting from the left.  Likewise, `Right` functions similarly:

```
=RIGHT(F2,4)
```

This returns `1320`, returning the 4 characters starting from the right.

You can use a combination of `Mid` and `Find` to dynamically find characters or strings based off of defined characters.  Here are a few examples of ways to dynamically isloate values in your string.  Keep in mind the key to these examples is the nested `Find` formula, where the inner most `Find` is the first character to start at in the string.

**1)** Return 2 characters after the second `:` character

In cell F2 I need to isolate the "92":

```
=MID(F2,FIND(":",F2,FIND(":",F2)+1)+1,2)
```

The inner most `Find` locates the first `:` in the string (4 characters in).  We add the `+1` to move to the 5th character (moving beyond the first `:` so the second Find will not see it) and move to the next Find which starts looking for `:` again from that character.  This second Find returns 10, as the second `:` is the 10th character in the string.  The `Mid` formula takes over here.  The formula is saying,  Starting at the 10th character return the following 2 characters.  Returning two characters is dictated by the 2 at the end of the formula (the last part of the `Mid` formula).

**2)** In this case I need to find the 2 characters after the 3rd `:` in the string.  In this case "99":

```
=MID(F2,FIND(":",F2,FIND(":",F2,FIND(":",F2)+1)+1)+1,2)
```

You can see we have simply added one more nested `Find` to the formula in example 1.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to help you about this, I am not a professional so you may face some problems. First of all my solution contains 2 columns to be added to the source column as you can see below. However you can improve formulas with this principle.

[image]

```
Column B Formula:
=LEFT(A2,FIND(":",A2,1)-1)

Column C Formula:
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,":","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,":","")))))
```

Comment: I would really appreciate if the one whoever negative voted can leave a comment about the reason.

Comment: @pnuts I think from this point he/she can handle the rest. I have given the most useful result and did not read the comments. sorry about that. in the original post my answer was requested.